Migrating LaTeX code from Markdown to Eisvogel
I have a combo LaTeX/Markdown question hoping someone can answer.
I am using Markdown for all my writing, but I am also heavily leaning into the Eisvogel template. I have been able to enable several very nice functional LaTeX modifications into Markdown.
Currently, I am using the LaTeX awesomebox package and the FontAwesome5 icons in my Markdown documents. However, I am trying to make this easier for many of my fellow devs who do not know LaTeX.
Currently, I do the following in Markdown to show custom Question and Answer blocks:
\awesomebox[maroon]{2pt}{\faQuestionCircle}{maroon}{\textbf{Question:} How do you do the thing?}

\awesomebox[brandgreen]{2pt}{\faLightbulb}{brandgreen}{\textbf{Answer:} You do the thing this way.}

I did the following in the Eisvogel template to make certain this works:
% Enable awesomebox and fontawesome5 icons for callouts
\usepackage{awesomebox}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{verbatim}

My Markdown file generates the icons and adminition blocks the way I want them; a red question mark for the question and a green lightbulb for the answer, followed by the necessary text.
However, this is too complicated for some of the devs who prefer Markdown only. They are willing to use the following convention to show code:
::: code
This is a block of code
:::

I also customized several other callout boxes in the following manner in Eisvogel using the tcolorbox package:
% tcolorbox
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{norm-box}{colback=gray!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=gray!60!black}
\newtcolorbox{info-box}{colback=cyan!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=cyan!60!black}
\newtcolorbox{warn-box}{colback=orange!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=orange!80!black}
\newtcolorbox{error-box}{colback=red!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=red!75!black}
\newtcolorbox{attn-box}{colback=green!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=green!75!black}
\newtcolorbox{code-box}{colback=codeblock!100!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=gray!0!white}
\newtcolorbox{learn-box}{colback=blue!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=blue!40!black,title=\textbf{Objectives:}}
\newtcolorbox{scenario-box}{colback=orange!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=orange!80!black,title=\textbf{Scenario:}}
\newtcolorbox{outline-box}{colback=cyan!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=cyan!60!black,title=\textbf{Outline:}}
\newtcolorbox{prereqs-box}{colback=red!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=red!60!black,title=\textbf{Prerequisites:}}
\newtcolorbox{labtime-box}{colback=yellow!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=yellow!60!black,title=\textbf{Lab:}}

My question is:
Is it possible to port the whole \awesomebox[blah] script into the Eisvogel template? Can my users use the triple colon convention ort something similar to use custom icons in their basic Markdown?
I want to make it easier for users to add their questions and answers without the having to learn more LaTeX.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance. Happy to provide example cvustomizations from my customize Eisvogel template.

Eisvogel has some examples in the GitHub repo that show how it's done, e.g. here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template/master/examples/boxes-with-pandoc-latex-environment-and-awesomebox/document.md and here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template/master/examples/boxes-with-pandoc-latex-environment-and-tcolorbox/document.md

Nice. I do recall looking at these some time back, but forgot about them. I'll check it out. Thanks.

Just checked it out. Yes, these are for the basic five icons used by the \awesomebox package. I was hoping to add additional code to either the Pandoc preamble or to the Eisvogel template so I could use icons from FontAwesome5. The posting on the Wandmalfarbe site does not address FontAwesome5 icons.

It would help, if you could provide some code. But following the examples, it should be easy to add your definitions to the yaml frontmatter. You have to a) define the new boxes in header-includes and b) register the boxes with pandoc-latex-environment

Gotcha. I forgot about the pandoc-latex-environment filter. That seems like it should be obvious now. Much appreciated.

For Your followup question - I've made a small Lua script for pandoc:
--[[
admonition boxes, e.g:

::: warning
:::

awesomebox package supports 'note', 'tip', 'warning', 'caution', 'important'
other custom types have to be defined in header-includes (see below)

header-includes:
    # enable parsing markdown in custom environment:
    # (e.g. use \Begin{admonition} ... \End{admonition})
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    - \let\Begin\begin
    - \let\End\end
    #
    # custom environment for admonition boxes:
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    - \usepackage{awesomebox}
    #
    - \newenvironment{questionblock}
        {\begin{awesomeblock}[orange]{2pt}{\faQuestionCircle}{orange}}
        {\end{awesomeblock}}
]]

local admonitions = pandoc.List:new {'note', 'tip', 'warning', 'caution', 'important', 'question'}

function Div(elem)
  local adm = elem.classes[1]

  if admonitions:includes(adm) then
    return {
      pandoc.RawBlock("latex", "\\Begin{" .. adm .. "block}"),
      elem,
      -- \setlength{\parskip}{-1em} to gobble the extra newline before End
      pandoc.RawBlock("latex", "\\setlength{\\parskip}{-1em}\n\\End{" .. adm .. "block}")
    }
  end
end

You can define Your own types by adding them to the admonitions list in the script and defining them in header-includes section (see the sample for question).

I figured out how to reference a Lua filter. I copied the text above to a static file called "admonition.lua" and then in my preamble, I called the filter using the line "--lua-filter admonition.lua". However, my knowledge of how to build a filter is extremely limited, so I was getting the following error:
Error producing PDF.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.773 \Begin

You can define the Begin and End commands in the header-includes parameter in YAML metadata block (refer to https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#layout) for a sample.
Like so:
header-includes:
  - \let\Begin\begin
  - \let\End\end


Thanks @priiduonu. I will give it another try today. I am determined to get Lua filters working on my end. This seems like the best solution to solving many of my special requests. Thankds for the help.

I solved my issue.
Like I mentioned in my original post, I wanted to customize the Markdown code to limit the amount of LaTeX code that appears. Here is what I did to solve this:
Within the Eisvogel template (eisvogel.tex), add the following lines someplace in the code. I added my lines around line 690.
%% Testing newcommands, question and answers
\newcommand{\question}[1]{\awesomebox[maroon]{2pt}{\faQuestionCircle}{maroon}{#1}}
\newcommand{\answer}[1]{\awesomebox[brandgreen]{2pt}{\faLightbulb}{brandgreen}{#1}}

Basically, we have moved the code out of Markdown and placed it in Eisvogel. We created two new commands and we called them \question and \answer. Note the preceeding forward-slash.
This is how we will use them in Markdown. We create the new command using the following definitions:
\newcommand{cmd}[args]{def}
\renewcommand{cmd}[args]{def}


The command name is \question or \answer.
There is only a single argument, or [1] , which works like input from the user.
The definition is the string of LaTeX code.
The argument or #1 is added to the end and acts as input from the user in the Markdown file.

Next, moving to the Markdown file, formulate your questions and answers in the following manner:
\question{\textbf{Question:} What flags in the output state what virtualization support is
available on this server?}

\answer{\textbf{Answer:} Multiple flags show up: \texttt{Virtualization: VT-x}, \texttt{Hypervisor
vendor: KVM}, and \texttt{Virtualization type: full}. These flags provide information about the
type of virtualization support available on this server.}

Note the use of LaTeX tags to make the questions bolded and the flags as true type.
Next, build the file as you would normally.
Here is an example of the output:

Followup Question:
If anyone knows an even easier way to do this and remove even more LaTeX code from Markdown, I would appreciate it. In fact, something like the following would be perfect for my devs:
::: question
Question: What color is the sky?
:::

::: answer
Answer: The sky is blue.
:::

The triple colon and question variable would be replaced by the red question mark icon and the vertical red bar to its right. Likewise with the triple colon and answer would be the green lightbulb.
This way I can remove all LaTeX code from markdown and use the pandoc-latex-environment template. I have looked over the syntax for this filter but fear I am missing something.
Thanks.
